# 2.8 Grid disappears in Orthographic mode and returns in perspective mode

Tags: orthographic

The X Y Z grid disappears in Object top/front Orthographic mode.  I'd still like to see the grid in that mode.  Any way to turn it back on and keep it on?  The Grid is all on in the Overlay settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [reported](https://developer.blender.org/T61632) and it's been fixed already with the commit [rB4bbd1b9610f6d85079ea5bc31fc1949f8409a1a4](https://developer.blender.org/rB4bbd1b9610f6d85079ea5bc31fc1949f8409a1a4). Just update your Blender version.